# Do node operators for chainlink pay the gas for the transaction or does the intiator?

Tags: hyperlink, smartcontracts, chainlink

With the chain link node their are two transactions, the request and the response.
What portion of the gas fees are paid by the node?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, there are 2 transactions with a Chainlink node. 1 with the request, and 1 with the response.

#### The requester pays the request, the node pays the response.

More info:
The requester submits a transaction that emits a log to the chain. The log is then read off-chain by a chainlink node, who then performs whatever actions specified in the log. Once the node has the data, it calls the fulfill or callback function in a 2nd transaction with the data.